# Scroll to bottom not detecting correctly when scrolling fast on some devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to detect the page bottom position scrolled position using a pure javascript function. This is working fine on all desktop browsers and andriod IOS devices. But when I scrolling fast, it is not correctly detecting the page bottom on some devices.(Eg: Samsung galaxy s9)

```
trackScrolling = () => {
 let scrolledTop = 0;
 if (document.documentElement) {
   scrolledTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 } else if (document.body) {
   scrolledTop = document.body.scrollTop;
 }

 let scrollableHeight;
 if (document.documentElement) {
   scrollableHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
 } else if (document.body) {
   scrollableHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
 }

 // 1000 is just a number which is greater than 0.
 const diffToBottom = scrollableHeight ? scrollableHeight - (scrolledTop + window.innerHeight) : 1000;
 if (diffToBottom <= 0) {
  this.props.doLoadMore();
 }
}
```

In Galaxy S9, diffToBottom value is around 55 px. But if I sroll slowly it is 0.
Does anyone has an idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Issue is not with the offset.
We need to add a timeout when handling scroll events. Otherwise browser will Queue few scrolls and lost some scrolling events. That is why it is working when scrolling slowly.
Adding a 200 milliseconds timeout did the fix.